# Customisation of git branch --list format, similar to default --verbose

Tags: git

I like the formatting of git branch --verbose, but I'd like to add some extra fields.

In order to do this I think I need to use the --format option, but I can't seem to recreate the default --verbose formatting with a --format string.

Eg the default output looks like this (with the current branch, `master` highlighted in green):

```
$ git branch --verbose
  develop 41a12c2 Merge pull request #1092 from timothycrosley/feature/fix-issue-1088
* master  36f8c39 Fix up typo, replace resovled with resolved
```

The closest I've managed to get to reproducing this is:

```
git branch --list --format "%(align:width=13)%(HEAD)%(if)%(HEAD)%(then)%(color:green)%(end) %(refname:short)%(end)%(objectname:short) %(subject)" 
  develop    41a12c2 Merge pull request #1092 from timothycrosley/feature/fix-issue-1088
* master  36f8c39 Fix up typo, replace resovled with resolved
```

(with the whole line * highlighted in green).

- Is it even possible to reproduce the `--verbose` format with `--format`?
- The align:width seems to be a magic value, based on the widest branch name width - is it possible to reproduce this?
- I think I've hit bug between `%(align:width)` and `%(color:` - adding the color code changes the alignment?

This is using git version 2.20.1 in bash on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: As a sort of general rule (useless in the face of bugs :-) ) both `git branch --format` and `git rev-list --format` *ought* to be able to produce the same output that you get by default, i.e., the default *should* be that it executes a built in `--format`. That was the goal of adding the `--format` directives. Whether that goal has actually been achieved yet, I have no idea; your experiments suggest it has not.

Comment: As for figuring out the widest branch name, you could just use a two-pass algorithm: use `git for-each-ref` over the branch names to scan and count their widths, and take a maximum. (This of course requires using a pipe to something like awk.) But if the color directives mess with the columns, that's just a bug.